# How to make height of image same as width in fluid layout for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a web application using the fluid layout for twitter bootstrap. My code looks like below.

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="offset1 span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4 border-line">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/category">name_of_item</a></h4>
                             <a target="_blank" href="link_for_item">
                                <img class="item-size" src="photo.url"/>
                            </a>
                            <p> quick_summary|safe </p>
                        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 border-line">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="/category">name_of_item</a></h4>
                             <a target="_blank" href="link_for_item">
                                <img class="item-size" src="photo.url"/>
                            </a>
                            <p>quick_summary</p>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my css looks like below for item-size

```
 .item-size{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
  }
```

In the above example everything is working fine except the height for the image item. Image width is changing whenever i change to different value (example: 60%), but the height value is not having any effect on the size. I have tried wrapping the  element with div class of .item-size and even that did not have any effect. Can anyone help me how i can set the height value which will have effect on the height of the image ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "having effect on the height"? Do you want your image to preserve the aspect ration? And effect did you want to make by setting `height: 50%;`? As far as I know it should make the image 50% height of the height of container it is embedded. If this container (usually just the div) is not changing height responsively then the height of your image will not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify the height by percentage, unless you had set a height for the tag which is wrapping the img. So you have to set the height in pixels. ex.:

```
.item-size{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

if you still want to use % you have to set a height for a `wrapper div`.

Comment: Yes, or to simplify your life, you could set the height on the span10: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/BedwM/

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i change the height to 200px, does that not mean it's fluid responsive anymore as the height fixed at 200px even when i resize my window? Is there anyway i can make height also responsive?

Comment: If you set the height on the span in pixels, you can set the height of the image in percentage. But what do you mean responsive height?